# Populate a dropdown menu on a website using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, excel-2010

I am trying to populate the website https://doaj.org/application/new with information I have collected in an excel sheet.
I managed to fill most of the form by the code below.
But I am a beginner with this and I have problems to get a code that is populating/choosing the fields for question 6,7,8,12,34 and 35. The code that I tried to use is not working with this fields (for example:

```
Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("title")
  Item.Value = Range("C1")
```

), so I can't enter the information that I have in the table directly to those fields.
I already searched for codes that could help me but nothing worked.

Here is my code that is runnig good so far, but the mentioned questions I can't enter to the website.

```
    Sub Tool()
  Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
  Dim IEdoc As HTMLDocument
  Dim Item As Variant
  'Open IE and go to the side
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https://doaj.org/application/new"
  'Wait until side is loaded
  Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
  Loop
  'Get the body
  Set IEdoc = IE.document
  'Find each field and fill out
  'Questions are numbered
  '1
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("title")
  Item.Value = Range("C1")
  '2
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("url")
  Item.Value = Range("C2")
  '3
  If Not Range("C3") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("alternative_title").Item.Value = Range("C3")
  '4
  If Range("C4") <> "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("pissn")
  Item.Value = Range("C4")
  '5
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("eissn")
  Item.Value = Range("C5")
  '6----------------------------
  '7----------------------------
  '8----------------------------
 '18
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("submission_charges_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C18")
  '9
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("contact_name")
  Item.Value = Range("C9")
  '10
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("contact_email")
  Item.Value = Range("C10")
  '11
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("confirm_contact_email")
  Item.Value = Range("C11")
  '12
  IE.document.all.Item("country").Value = Range("C12")
  '13
  IE.document.getElementById(Range("C13")).Click
  '14
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("processing_charges_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C14")
  '15
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("processing_charges_amount")
  Item.Value = Range("C15")
  '16
  IE.document.all.Item("processing_charges_currency").Value = Range("C16")
  '17
  If Range("C17") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("submission_charges-0").Click
  If Range("C17") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("submission_charges-1").Click
  '19
  If Not Range("C19") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("submission_charges_amount")
  Item.Value = Range("C19")
  '20
  If Not Range("C20") = "0" Then IE.document.all.Item("submission_charges_currency").Value = Range("C20")
  '21
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("articles_last_year")
  Item.Value = Range("C21")
  '22
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("articles_last_year_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C22")
  '23
  If Range("C23") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("waiver_policy-0").Click
  If Range("C23") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("waiver_policy-1").Click
  '24
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("waiver_policy_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C24")
  '25
  If Range("C26") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-0").Click
  If Range("C27") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-1").Click
  If Range("C28") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-2").Click
  If Range("C29") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-3").Click
  If Range("C30") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-4").Click
  If Range("C31") <> "0" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-5").Click
  If Range("C32") <> "0" Then IE.document.getElementById("digital_archiving_policy-6").Click
  If Range("C31") <> "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("digital_archiving_policy_library")
  Item.Value = Range("C31")
  If Range("C32") <> "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("digital_archiving_policy_other")
  Item.Value = Range("C32")
  '26
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("digital_archiving_policy_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C33")
  '27
  If Range("C34") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("crawl_permission-0").Click
  If Range("C34") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("crawl_permission-1").Click
  '28
  If Range("C36") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("article_identifiers-0").Click
  If Range("C37") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("article_identifiers-1").Click
  If Range("C38") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("article_identifiers-2").Click
  If Range("C39") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("article_identifiers-3").Click
  If Not Range("C40") = "0" Then IE.document.getElementById("article_identifiers-4").Click
  If Not Range("C40") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("article_identifiers_other").Item.Value = Range("C40")
  '29
  If Range("C41") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("metadata_provision-0").Click
  If Range("C41") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("metadata_provision-1").Click
  '30
  IE.document.getElementById(Range("C42")).Click
  '31
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("download_statistics_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C43")
  '32
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("first_fulltext_oa_year")
  Item.Value = Range("C44")
  '33
  If Range("C46") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("fulltext_format-0").Click
  If Range("C47") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("fulltext_format-1").Click
  If Range("C48") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("fulltext_format-2").Click
  If Range("C49") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("fulltext_format-3").Click
  If Not Range("C50") = "0" Then IE.document.getElementById("fulltext_format-4").Click
  If Not Range("C50") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("fulltext_format_other").Item.Value = Range("C50")
  '34----------------------------
  '35----------------------------
  '36
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("editorial_board_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C55")
  '37
  IE.document.all.Item("review_process").Value = Range("C56")
  '38
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("review_process_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C57")
  '39
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("aims_scope_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C58")
  '40
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("instructions_authors_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C59")
  '41
  If Range("C60") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("plagiarism_screening-0").Click
  If Range("C60") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("plagiarism_screening-1").Click
  '42
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("plagiarism_screening_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C61")
  '43
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("publication_time")
  Item.Value = Range("C62")
  '44
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("oa_statement_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C66")
  '45
  If Range("C69") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("license_embedded-0").Click
  If Range("C69") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("license_embedded-1").Click
  '46
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("license_embedded_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C71")
  '47
  If Range("C72") = "CC BY" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-0").Click
  If Range("C72") = "CC BY-NC" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-1").Click
  If Range("C72") = "CC BY-NC-ND" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-2").Click
  If Range("C72") = "CC BY-NC-SA" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-3").Click
  If Range("C72") = "CC BY-ND" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-4").Click
  If Range("C72") = "CC BY-SA" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-5").Click
  If Range("C72") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-6").Click
  If Range("C72") = "Other" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("license_other")
  Item.Value = Range("C73")
  If Range("C72") = "Other" Then IE.document.getElementById("license-7").Click
  '48
  If Range("C75") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("license_checkbox-0").Click
  If Range("C76") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("license_checkbox-1").Click
  If Range("C77") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("license_checkbox-2").Click
  If Range("C78") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("license_checkbox-3").Click
  '49
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("license_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C79")
  '50
  If Range("C80") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("open_access-0").Click
  If Range("C80") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("open_access-1").Click
  '51
  If Range("C82") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-0").Click
  If Range("C83") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-1").Click
  If Range("C84") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-2").Click
  If Range("C85") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-3").Click
  If Range("C86") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-4").Click
  If Range("C87") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-5").Click
  If Range("C88") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("deposit_policy-6").Click
  If Not Range("C89") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("deposit_policy_other").Item.Value = Range("C89")
  '52
  If Range("C92") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("copyright-0").Click
  If Range("C92") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("copyright-1").Click
  If Not Range("C93") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("copyright_other").Item.Value = Range("C93")
  '53
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("copyright_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C94")
  '54
  If Range("C95") = "Yes" Then IE.document.getElementById("publishing_rights-0").Click
  If Range("C95") = "No" Then IE.document.getElementById("publishing_rights-1").Click
  If Not Range("C96") = "0" Then Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("publishing_rights_other").Item.Value = Range("C93")
  '55
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("publishing_rights_url")
  Item.Value = Range("C97")
  '56
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("suggester_name")
  Item.Value = Range("C100")
  '57
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("suggester_email")
  Item.Value = Range("C101")
  '58
  Item = IEdoc.getElementsByName("suggester_email_confirm")
  Item.Value = Range("C102")
End Sub
```

The html source for question 6 is:

```
<div class="control-group" id="publisher-container"><a class="animated" name="6"></a><label class="control-label" for="publisher"><a class="animated orange" href="#publisher-container" title="Link to this question" tabindex="-1">6)</a>&nbsp;Publisher&nbsp;<span class="red">*</span></label><div class="controls"><input class="input-xlarge" id="publisher" name="publisher" type="text" value=""></div>
```

The html source for question 7 is:

```
<div class="control-group" id="society_institution-container"><a class="animated" name="7"></a><label class="control-label" for="society_institution"><a class="animated orange" href="#society_institution-container" title="Link to this question" tabindex="-1">7)</a>&nbsp;Society or Institution</label><div class="controls"><input class="input-xlarge" id="society_institution" name="society_institution" type="text" value=""><p class="help-block">The name of the Society or Institution that the journal belongs to.</p></div>
```

The html source for question 8 is:

```
<div class="control-group" id="platform-container"><a class="animated" name="8"></a><label class="control-label" for="platform"><a class="animated orange" href="#platform-container" title="Link to this question" tabindex="-1">8)</a>&nbsp;Platform, Host or Aggregator</label><div class="controls"><input class="input-xlarge" id="platform" name="platform" type="text" value=""><p class="help-block">The name of the platform, host or aggregator of the journal content, e.g. OJS, HighWire Press, EBSCO etc.</p></div>
```

The html source for question 12 is (tried tho select a value for this box, but it didn't work):

```
<div class="control-group" id="country-container"><a class="animated" name="12"></a><label class="control-label" for="country"><a class="animated orange" href="#country-container" title="Link to this question" tabindex="-1">12)</a>&nbsp;In which country is the publisher of the journal based?&nbsp;<span class="red">*</span></label><div class="controls"><select class="input-large" id="country" name="country"><option value=""></option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="DZ">Algeria</option><option value="AS">American Samoa</option><option value="AD">Andorra</option><option value="AO">Angola</option><option value="AI">Anguilla</option><option value="AQ">Antarctica</option><option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option><option value="AR">Argentina</option><option value="AM">Armenia</option><option value="AW">Aruba</option><option value="AU">Australia</option><option value="AT">Austria</option><option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option><option value="BS">Bahamas</option><option value="BH">Bahrain</option><option value="BD">Bangladesh</option><option value="BB">Barbados</option><option value="BY">Belarus</option><option value="BE">Belgium</option><option value="BZ">Belize</option><option value="BJ">Benin</option><option value="BM">Bermuda</option><option value="BT">Bhutan</option><option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option><option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option><option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option><option value="BW">Botswana</option><option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option><option value="BR">Brazil</option><option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option><option value="BG">Bulgaria</option><option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option><option value="BI">Burundi</option><option value="KH">Cambodia</option><option value="CM">Cameroon</option><option value="CA">Canada</option><option value="CV">Cape Verde</option><option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option><option value="CF">Central African Republic</option><option value="TD">Chad</option><option value="CL">Chile</option><option value="CN">China</option><option value="CX">Christmas Island</option><option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option><option value="CO">Colombia</option><option value="KM">Comoros</option><option value="CG">Congo</option><option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option><option value="CK">Cook Islands</option><option value="CR">Costa Rica</option><option value="HR">Croatia</option><option value="CU">Cuba</option><option value="CW">Curaçao</option><option value="CY">Cyprus</option><option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option><option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option><option value="DK">Denmark</option><option value="DJ">Djibouti</option><option value="DM">Dominica</option><option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option><option value="EC">Ecuador</option><option value="EG">Egypt</option><option value="SV">El Salvador</option><option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="ER">Eritrea</option><option value="EE">Estonia</option><option value="ET">Ethiopia</option><option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option><option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option><option value="FJ">Fiji</option><option value="FI">Finland</option><option value="FR">France</option><option value="GF">French Guiana</option><option value="PF">French Polynesia</option><option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option><option value="GA">Gabon</option><option value="GM">Gambia</option><option value="GE">Georgia</option><option value="DE">Germany</option><option value="GH">Ghana</option><option value="GI">Gibraltar</option><option value="GR">Greece</option><option value="GL">Greenland</option><option value="GD">Grenada</option><option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option><option value="GU">Guam</option><option value="GT">Guatemala</option><option value="GG">Guernsey</option><option value="GN">Guinea</option><option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="GY">Guyana</option><option value="HT">Haiti</option><option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Mcdonald Islands</option><option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option><option value="HN">Honduras</option><option value="HK">Hong Kong</option><option value="HU">Hungary</option><option value="IS">Iceland</option><option value="IN">India</option><option value="ID">Indonesia</option><option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option><option value="IQ">Iraq</option><option value="IE">Ireland</option><option value="IM">Isle of Man</option><option value="IL">Israel</option><option value="IT">Italy</option><option value="JM">Jamaica</option><option value="JP">Japan</option><option value="JE">Jersey</option><option value="JO">Jordan</option><option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option><option value="KE">Kenya</option><option value="KI">Kiribati</option><option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option><option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option><option value="KW">Kuwait</option><option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option><option value="LV">Latvia</option><option value="LB">Lebanon</option><option value="LS">Lesotho</option><option value="LR">Liberia</option><option value="LY">Libya</option><option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option><option value="LT">Lithuania</option><option value="LU">Luxembourg</option><option value="MO">Macao</option><option value="MK">Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of</option><option value="MG">Madagascar</option><option value="MW">Malawi</option><option value="MY">Malaysia</option><option value="MV">Maldives</option><option value="ML">Mali</option><option value="MT">Malta</option><option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option><option value="MQ">Martinique</option><option value="MR">Mauritania</option><option value="MU">Mauritius</option><option value="YT">Mayotte</option><option value="MX">Mexico</option><option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option><option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option><option value="MC">Monaco</option><option value="MN">Mongolia</option><option value="ME">Montenegro</option><option value="MS">Montserrat</option><option value="MA">Morocco</option><option value="MZ">Mozambique</option><option value="MM">Myanmar</option><option value="NA">Namibia</option><option value="NR">Nauru</option><option value="NP">Nepal</option><option value="NL">Netherlands</option><option value="NC">New Caledonia</option><option value="NZ">New Zealand</option><option value="NI">Nicaragua</option><option value="NE">Niger</option><option value="NG">Nigeria</option><option value="NU">Niue</option><option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option><option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="NO">Norway</option><option value="OM">Oman</option><option value="PK">Pakistan</option><option value="PW">Palau</option><option value="PS">Palestine, State of</option><option value="PA">Panama</option><option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option><option value="PY">Paraguay</option><option value="PE">Peru</option><option value="PH">Philippines</option><option value="PN">Pitcairn</option><option value="PL">Poland</option><option value="PT">Portugal</option><option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option><option value="QA">Qatar</option><option value="RO">Romania</option><option value="RU">Russian Federation</option><option value="RW">Rwanda</option><option value="RE">Réunion</option><option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option><option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option><option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option><option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option><option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option><option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option><option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option><option value="WS">Samoa</option><option value="SM">San Marino</option><option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option><option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="SN">Senegal</option><option value="RS">Serbia</option><option value="SC">Seychelles</option><option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option><option value="SG">Singapore</option><option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option><option value="SK">Slovakia</option><option value="SI">Slovenia</option><option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option><option value="SO">Somalia</option><option value="ZA">South Africa</option><option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option><option value="SS">South Sudan</option><option value="ES">Spain</option><option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option><option value="SD">Sudan</option><option value="SR">Suriname</option><option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option><option value="SZ">Swaziland</option><option value="SE">Sweden</option><option value="CH">Switzerland</option><option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option><option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option><option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option><option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option><option value="TH">Thailand</option><option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option><option value="TG">Togo</option><option value="TK">Tokelau</option><option value="TO">Tonga</option><option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option><option value="TN">Tunisia</option><option value="TR">Turkey</option><option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option><option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option><option value="TV">Tuvalu</option><option value="UG">Uganda</option><option value="UA">Ukraine</option><option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom</option><option value="US">United States</option><option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option><option value="UY">Uruguay</option><option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option><option value="VU">Vanuatu</option><option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option><option value="VN">Viet Nam</option><option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option><option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option><option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option><option value="EH">Western Sahara</option><option value="YE">Yemen</option><option value="ZM">Zambia</option><option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option></select><p class="help-block">Select the country where the publishing company carries out its business activities. Addresses registered via a registered agent are not allowed.</p></div>
```

The html source for question 34 is:

```
<div class="control-group" id="keywords-container"><a class="animated" name="34"></a><label class="control-label" for="keywords"><a class="animated orange" href="#keywords-container" title="Link to this question" tabindex="-1">34)</a>&nbsp;Add keyword(s) that best describe the journal (comma delimited)&nbsp;<span class="red">*</span></label><div class="controls"><input class="input-xlarge" id="keywords" name="keywords" type="text" value=""><p class="help-block">Maximum 6. Keywords must be in English.</p></div>
```

The html source for question 35 is:

```
<div class="control-group" id="languages-container"><a class="animated" name="35"></a><label class="control-label" for="languages"><a class="animated orange" href="#languages-container" title="Link to this question" tabindex="-1">35)</a>&nbsp;Select the language(s) that the Full Text of the articles is published in&nbsp;<span class="red">*</span></label><div class="controls"><select class="input-xlarge" id="languages" multiple name="languages"><option value="AB">Abkhazian</option><option value="AA">Afar</option><option value="AF">Afrikaans</option><option value="AK">Akan</option><option value="SQ">Albanian</option><option value="AM">Amharic</option><option value="AR">Arabic</option><option value="AN">Aragonese</option><option value="HY">Armenian</option><option value="AS">Assamese</option><option value="AV">Avaric</option><option value="AE">Avestan</option><option value="AY">Aymara</option><option value="AZ">Azerbaijani</option><option value="BM">Bambara</option><option value="BA">Bashkir</option><option value="EU">Basque</option><option value="BE">Belarusian</option><option value="BN">Bengali</option><option value="BH">Bihari languages</option><option value="BI">Bislama</option><option value="NB">Bokmål, Norwegian; Norwegian Bokmål</option><option value="BS">Bosnian</option><option value="BR">Breton</option><option value="BG">Bulgarian</option><option value="MY">Burmese</option><option value="CA">Catalan; Valencian</option><option value="KM">Central Khmer</option><option value="CH">Chamorro</option><option value="CE">Chechen</option><option value="NY">Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja</option><option value="ZH">Chinese</option><option value="CU">Church Slavic; Old Slavonic; Church Slavonic; Old Bulgarian; Old Church Slavonic</option><option value="CV">Chuvash</option><option value="KW">Cornish</option><option value="CO">Corsican</option><option value="CR">Cree</option><option value="HR">Croatian</option><option value="CS">Czech</option><option value="DA">Danish</option><option value="DV">Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian</option><option value="NL">Dutch; Flemish</option><option value="DZ">Dzongkha</option><option value="EN">English</option><option value="EO">Esperanto</option><option value="ET">Estonian</option><option value="EE">Ewe</option><option value="FO">Faroese</option><option value="FJ">Fijian</option><option value="FI">Finnish</option><option value="FR">French</option><option value="FF">Fulah</option><option value="GD">Gaelic; Scottish Gaelic</option><option value="GL">Galician</option><option value="LG">Ganda</option><option value="KA">Georgian</option><option value="DE">German</option><option value="EL">Greek, Modern (1453-)</option><option value="GN">Guarani</option><option value="GU">Gujarati</option><option value="HT">Haitian; Haitian Creole</option><option value="HA">Hausa</option><option value="HE">Hebrew</option><option value="HZ">Herero</option><option value="HI">Hindi</option><option value="HO">Hiri Motu</option><option value="HU">Hungarian</option><option value="IS">Icelandic</option><option value="IO">Ido</option><option value="IG">Igbo</option><option value="ID">Indonesian</option><option value="IA">Interlingua (International Auxiliary Language Association)</option><option value="IE">Interlingue; Occidental</option><option value="IU">Inuktitut</option><option value="IK">Inupiaq</option><option value="GA">Irish</option><option value="IT">Italian</option><option value="JA">Japanese</option><option value="JV">Javanese</option><option value="KL">Kalaallisut; Greenlandic</option><option value="KN">Kannada</option><option value="KR">Kanuri</option><option value="KS">Kashmiri</option><option value="KK">Kazakh</option><option value="KI">Kikuyu; Gikuyu</option><option value="RW">Kinyarwanda</option><option value="KY">Kirghiz; Kyrgyz</option><option value="KV">Komi</option><option value="KG">Kongo</option><option value="KO">Korean</option><option value="KJ">Kuanyama; Kwanyama</option><option value="KU">Kurdish</option><option value="LO">Lao</option><option value="LA">Latin</option><option value="LV">Latvian</option><option value="LI">Limburgan; Limburger; Limburgish</option><option value="LN">Lingala</option><option value="LT">Lithuanian</option><option value="LU">Luba-Katanga</option><option value="LB">Luxembourgish; Letzeburgesch</option><option value="MK">Macedonian</option><option value="MG">Malagasy</option><option value="MS">Malay</option><option value="ML">Malayalam</option><option value="MT">Maltese</option><option value="GV">Manx</option><option  [....]ption><option value="ZA">Zhuang; Chuang</option><option value="ZU">Zulu</option></select><p class="help-block">You can select multiple languages.</p></div>
```

There are different values that I tried to choose directly, but it didn't worked.

I know it is a lot I am asking and I don't want to bother this great community here as I got already help for most of my problems by visiting related problems and their answers on this page. But this I couldn't figure out. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: One immediate problem I can see is that you're using `getElementsByName` and then trying to assign a value to it. `getElementsByName` does not return a single element; rather, as the name suggests, it returns a collection of elements. You need to pick one member of that collection if you want to assign values to its properties (e.g. `getElementsByName("title")(0).Value=Range("A1")`).